# Strange behavior of for loop inside ReactJS Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have created a ReactJS App which generates fake random data. In one section as *random number generator* in that one component generates random of digits of the given length. Check it here https://newcodingera.com/fakeformdata/#/numbers
It has one input field to increment/decrement the length value of the number. When I decrease it till the 1 then it should produce any random(0 to 9) number of length one but it produces the two digits random number,

The last method `getNumberOfDigits` is responsible for producing the random number of the given length using `for loop` but I think it performs one extra iteration when I call this method. The strange thing is that when I take that method & run it on any online JavaScript editor it gives me the correct output, So I am confused whether this problem is caused by the JS or ReactJS.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import faker from "faker";
import Input from "../Input";
import PageHeader from "../layouts/PageHeader";
import CreditCardGenerator from "creditcard-generator";

export default class NumbersGenerator extends Component {
  state = {
    digits: 10,
    numberOfDigits: getNumberOfDigits(),
    values: getFakeValues(),
  };

  refreshData = () => {
    this.setState({
      numberOfDigits: getNumberOfDigits(this.state.digits),
      values: getFakeValues(),
    });
  };

  onChangeHandler = e => {
    var index = e.nativeEvent.target.selectedIndex;
    const type = e.nativeEvent.target[index].text;

    this.setState({ values: getFakeValues(type) });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    this.setState({ numberOfDigits: getNumberOfDigits(this.state.digits) });
  };

  render() {
    const { number, cvv, expiryDate } = this.state.values.card;
    const { digits, numberOfDigits } = this.state;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <PageHeader
          title="Generate Fake & Random Numbers"
          subtitle="Generate fake whole number, integer number, etc..."
          onRefreash={this.refreshData}
        />

        <div className="card mt-3 box-shadow">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">Fake Credit Cards Numbers</h5>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  name="credit-card"
                  value={number}
                  placeholder="Creadit Card"
                  label="Creadit Card Number"
                />

                <Input
                  name="cvv"
                  value={cvv}
                  placeholder="Creadit Card"
                  label="Fake CVV Number"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="col">
                <div className="form-group">
                  <label htmlFor="exampleFormControlSelect1">Select Card Type</label>
                  <select
                    onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
                    className="form-control"
                    name="imgtype"
                  >
                    <option value="Amex">Amex</option>
                    <option value="VISA">VISA</option>
                    <option value="Mastercard">Mastercard</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <Input
                  name="expiry-date"
                  value={expiryDate}
                  placeholder="Expiration Date"
                  label="Fake Expiration Date"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="card mt-3 box-shadow">
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">Random Numbers Of Digits</h5>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col">
                <Input
                  name="credit-card"
                  value={numberOfDigits}
                  placeholder="Number Of Digits"
                  label="Numbers"
                />
              </div>

              <div className="col">
                <label className="mr-2">Enter Number Of Digits</label>
                <div className="input-group add-on">
                  <input
                    type="number"
                    min="1"
                    value={digits}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Enter Number Of Digits"
                    name="digits"
                    id=""
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

function getFakeValues(cardType = "") {
  return {
    card: {
      number: getFakeCardNumber(cardType),
      cvv: getFakeCVV(),
      expiryDate: getFakeExpiryDate(),
    },
  };
}

function getFakeCardNumber(type = "") {
  return CreditCardGenerator.GenCC(type);
}

function getFakeCVV() {
  var cvv = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cvv += faker.random.number({ max: 9 }).toString();
  }
  return cvv;
}

function getFakeExpiryDate() {
  const fakeDate = faker.date.future(5);
  var d = new Date(fakeDate);
  var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
  var day = d.getDate();

  var output =
    (day < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    day +
    "-" +
    (month < 10 ? "0" : "") +
    month +
    "-" +
    d.getFullYear();

  return output;
}

function getNumberOfDigits(length = 10) {
  const numbersArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
  let constructedArray = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    constructedArray.push(numbersArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbersArray.length)]);
  }

  return constructedArray.join("");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely, you actually get a 1-digit random number once you decrease the digits to zero – and the same pattern repeats when you start increasing things again: it always lags behind by one setting.

This is because [`setState()` is not synchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), and when you do

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
this.setState({ numberOfDigits: getNumberOfDigits(this.state.digits) });
```

`this.state.digits` is not yet updated with the user's input.

You can add a callback to `this.setState` that *is* guaranteed to be called after the state is actually updated, like thus:

```
this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }, () => {
  this.setState({ numberOfDigits: getNumberOfDigits(this.state.digits) });
});
```